# É legal fazer questões referenciando as tags?

Tags: suporte, tags

Talvez a frase da pergunta não esteja clara, mas vou tentar descrever melhor aqui.

Existe uma [determinada questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43224/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-url-e-uri) no qual está sendo referenciando o URL e URI.

> O que é URL? O que é URI? São sinônimos?[...]

Eu poderia fazer desta forma abaixo?

> O que é [url](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url)? O que é [uri](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uri)? São sinônimos?

Num [outro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41517/como-descriptografar-md5):

> [...] Isso é possível ou uma string criptografada em [md5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/md5) não tem pode
>   ser descriptografada?

É legal para o site fazer questões referenciando as tags?

Comment: Acho que o campo de titulo não aceita esse tipo de formatação.

Comment: @diegofm não é no título, é no conteúdo da questão. Tanto é que nessa minha questão, só coloquei o conteúdo.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/101

Comment: @diegofm é que aparentemente ali parece um título, porém é conteúdo da questão: Qual a diferença entre URL e URI?

Comment: Entendi, mas então ai já entra mais em questão pessoal. Eu não uso com frequencia, só se o destaque for relevante.

Comment: @diegofm no link do bigown tem uma frase interessante que é legal considerar: "_[...]enquanto que o uso excessivo de-formatação acaba comprometendo a fluidez do discurso[...]_". Acho que vou considerar isso, porém eu acharia interessante inserir a tag, a não ser que essa mesma seja repetida muitas vezes. Desta forma, não seria muito viável.

Comment: Mas também repetir muito a palavra ou termo não é muito interessante.

Comment: Se aparecesse o quadro da descrição com o mouse-over, eu acho que seria útil. Mas não é o caso, só aparece a caixa com o fragmento quando você poe o mouse sobre as tags apresentadas embaixo da pergunta. No corpo é mero link. A única exceção onde eu vejo tag útil no corpo da pergunta é justamente quando o link para outras perguntas sobre o assunto é realmente útil.